# What is the right category in which to think of adjoints?

Tags: category-theory

I still find adjoints tricky to wrap my head around. I think this is possibly because my intuition for most constructions I've seen in category theory (functors, natural transformations, limits / colimits) has fundamentally to do with my geometric intuition for directed graphs and diagrams.

I think that I may be finding adjoints tricky because their data seems to twist several different categories around. To be more concrete with my question:

C and D are categories, and $F : C \to D$ and $G: D \to C$ are left and right adjoint functors. Is there a category in which the natural bijection between $Mor(F(A),B)$ and $Mor(A,G(B))$ naturally lives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It lives in the category of functors $C^{op} \times D \to \text{Set}$; this is the category of [profunctors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor) from $C$ to $D$.

Comment: So the data of an adjunction is a natural transformation between the functors $Mor(F(A),B)$ and $Mor(A,G(B))$ from $C^{op} \times D \to Set$ (given that $F$ and $G$ are functors)?

Comment: Actually, I think the convention is that a functor $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathcal{D} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is a profunctor from $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathcal{C}$. This is certainly the case on the cited page. A mnemonic for remembering this: the category of profunctors from $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the category of left adjoints $[\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] \to [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$, at least when $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are small.

Comment: @user: it's a natural isomorphism. There are also other equivalent ways of thinking about an adjunction which are useful and which you can find on the Wikipedia page, e.g. the unit-counit definition makes sense in any $2$-category.